# PostGIS query taking too long. >400ms

Tags: postgresql, postgis, query-performance

```
Select COUNT(*) from indiahighway_ref where (ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(indiahighway_ref.geom,2163),ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(73.919595 18.5622609)', 4326),2163),500))
```

It's taking too long. How can i optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I was unnecessary making it complex. ST_DWithin works faster with geography and is more accurate so I used ST_DWithin with geography and created index on geography to make the query run faster.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted an explain plan but I'm going to assume you don't have an index on the transformation so the database has to run `ST_Transform` on each row. As mentioned in the [manual](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) you will want to create it.

```
CREATE INDEX indiahighway_ref_geom_2163
  ON indiahighway_ref
  USING gist
  (ST_Transform(geom, 1163))
  WHERE geom IS NOT NULL;
```